# Why is there no red light on the CPU after I press the power button

Tags: boot, cpu, led

Today I got a 4 GB RAM for my PC. SO I turned on my PC, without this new RAM, and it gave a warning about wrong system time. So I pressed F2 and it loaded normally. Then I turned it off and inserted the new RAM but it failed to open. The computer powers up, the CPU fan starts running and there is this on and off sequence of green LED light on the DVD drive. And nothing else. No affirmative beep of booting up and the red light that lights up when the power is pressed is not lighting (actually I can see a constant, very dim red light there after the power key is pressed on. Not the normal bright and active one.) Maybe I messed up with some wires while inserting the RAM but I have remove and reinserted each and every one of the cables, from SATA to 4/8 pin. Also I removed the CMOS battery and inserted it again. Maybe the new RAM caused some problems. But even after removing the new RAM and trying again gave the same result. Also when I removed both the RAMs and trued to power on, the process that had been happening happened again, without any warning beep. Same fan running and nothing happening.
I am at the end of my wits now. Please help...

P.S.- I don't know whether it is significant or not but there is one more anomaly I noticed. When I press the power button the 3 LED's in the keyboard light together. Normal behavior. But then when nothing happens, no booting, I just pressed the NUM key to check whether the power is going to the keyboard or not. So for few times it responded by turning on and off as I pressed the key. But then it also stopped responding. There were no lights on the keyboard.

Comment: The NUM key thing is normal, it happens when you spam "del" to enter bios as well, after a few presses keyboard will not respond. || System time Get a new battery. It's cheap. || Red light: It's just a LED, there is a "front panel" connector on the motherboard, it must have slipped out, but it will do nothing. These LEDs help nothing, they are only for show. There are debug leds - it was a thing like 10 years ago for premium motherboards, but these are gone now. Best you can do is listen to any audio / beep sounds. Beeps can indicate quite a few errors. IF you have your pc speaker connected.

Comment: Back to the problem. The ram. You have to have COMPATIBLE ram! Check your motherboard manufacturer's website, and you can find a ram compatiblity chart there somewhere. Also check the specs of your motherboard, if it supports said speed, timing, etc. If not, it will NOT work. || No boot with no ram: Computer needs ram to have even a screen, put in the old ram, check if it works.

Comment: I tried to use the old RAM but still the same problem was there. Also I forgot to mention that this same exact problem occurred a few days back, when I was cleaning it. After many tries of removing and reinserting each and every wire and cable it started working. But I think I have surpassed the number of tries now with no result.